# What level of power requires registration?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers, avengers-initiative

After the Civil War event in the Marvel Comics universe, registration is required for super-powered beings.

Is there a cap on this? Do some people get out of this by being 'useless'? Are people enlisted, as well as registered?

Comment: Not sure if there's specificity relating to being "powered"? I reckon even a human vigilante putting on a mask to fight crime could technically be arrested for "fighting crime" unregistered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Registration is no longer required!  Huzzah!

However, back during the heyday of registration, Avengers: The Initiative gives us a good look into what powersets are registered, and what ends up happening.

Spoilers below.

> Cloud 9 is the example that immediately comes to mind.  At the beginning, she has no interest in superheroics, but the Initiative program turns her into a sniper.  Butterball, on the other hand, washes out of the program since he's not very useful in combat.

To answer your questions:  If there is a cap, it would only be to weed out people with purely ornamental powers.  Even these people might have to register, although training seems unlikely.  As shown in Avengers: The Initiative, registrees are trained to become superheroes, which serves a loose form of enlistment.